# Should I call a function that returns a promise immediately after setState or in the dependency array of useEffect()

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, react-hooks

My code (which seems to work ok) looks like this:

```
import { SplashScreen } from "@capacitor/splash-screen";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    init()
  }, [])

  const init = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("some_api")
    setData(response.data)
    await SplashScreen.hide()
  } 

  return (<div>{JSON.stringify(data)}<div>)
}
```

But I'm wondering if it's better practive to move the `await SplashScreen.hide()` function call to a useEffect() with the data in the dependency array like this:

```
import { SplashScreen } from "@capacitor/splash-screen";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    init()
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      await SplashScreen.hide()
    }
  }, [data])

  const init = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("some_api")
    setData(response.data)
  } 

  return (<div>{JSON.stringify(data)}<div>)
}
```

Note: SplashScreen.hide() returns a promise. Which way is better and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if you want to call `SplashScreen.hide()` after the data has been set or not. In the first case it's not guaranteed that the call will be made after the data is set since `setState` works async. In the second case though, you are explicitly calling `SplashScreen.hide()` after the state has been updated.

Note, since you're not doing anything with the promise returned from `SplashScreen.hide()`, it's not necessary to call it with `await`.

Comment: I want the data set before I call SplashScreen.hide() so I'll use the second approach. thanks!